Как спарсить 1 картинку с Яндекса
Мне нужно спарсить картинку с Яндекса, но при парсинге тег с ссылкой на картинку где-то теряется (то есть если посмотреть html код, то тег вроде там есть, но при Парсинге нет)
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ua = UserAgent

def load_data(url):
    response = requests.get(
        url,
        headers={"user-agent": f"{ua.random}"}
    )
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    
    info = soup.find('div', class_="SerpList-Content")
    info = info.find('div', class_="SerpList-RowLayout")
    
    print(info)
    

response = "Haval H2"
url = f"https://yandex.ru/images/search?from=tabbar&text={response}"

load_data(url)


Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?

Selenium в помощь
